# PHP - about filter sanitize string

Tags: php, mysql

A simple question, PHP 8.x from now not supporting FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,

> 'FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING' is deprecated.

Should i replace it with:

```
htmlspecialchars() // Already by default charset UTF-8
```

What i need:

- protect from XSS, where FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING removing `<in between>`.
- It's ok if client signed up with `<script>....(anyName)</script>` and get his name only without telling him. (Already filtered with JS but if he ignored that).

Example:

```
<?php
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userInput']);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ......... VALUES (:zname)");
$stmt->execute([
   ":zname" => $name
]);
```

Will be safe to use this example instead of `filter_var($_POST['userInput'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` ?

**Thank you.**

Comment: You only need to protect from XSS when you *display* user input on a web page. You can prevent XSS by wrapping user input with `htmlspecialchars()`. Your SQL code uses parameterized queries, and should be safe from XSS, even if you store `<script>` tags in the DB. As for [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection), that's another question.

Comment: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` striped tags so a closer replacement would be `strip_tags` . `htmlspecialchars` is closer to `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` . In the end if you use any of these then it is a good step towards protecting yourself from xss

Comment: @kmoser Thank you for the kink, i'm already using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

`htmlspecialchars` is for HTML.

PDO needs to escape characters in a different way.  Let `$pdo->prepare(...)` take care of things for you.

Note: That advice will leave `UTF-8` characters in the database (which is appropriate) instead of things that look like `&foobar;` (which works turns into the foobar character in HTML, but is otherwise a string of ascii characters).

I think that gets rid of your `clean` function.

Meanwhile, all connections, all columns, etc, should be set to `utf8mb4` (MySQL's term for UTF-8).

Comment: I'm Already using utf8_general_ci, All i want is be safe agains XSS, ( nothing 100% safe )..
should i use htmlspacialchars() ? (i was using FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) .. thanks.

Comment: Maybe it helps against XSS, but not against SQL Injection.

Comment: Last thing Mr. @RickJames , i'm removing ``( ' , " , &#39; , &#34; )`` From the string,
will that help with SQL Injection ?

Comment: No, it is more complex than that.  Too much to discuss in a Comment.